# Cordova: Keep socket.io connection alive

Tags: angularjs, cordova, socket.io, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an Apache Cordova app with Ionic Framework that should communicate through a WebSocket with my server and I use the Socket.Io library for it. Now there are two prolems I face:

1. When the app goes into the background (cordova `pause` event), for example via the home or standby button, after a while, the socket gets closed & the client gets disconnected.
2. When I exit the app via the hardware back button on android devices, the socket even gets closed immediately.

What I have tried so far:

- `socket.io.reconnect()` or `socket.io.connect()` when `disconnect` event fires
- same thing when `$destroy` event on `$scope` fires (Ionic works on top of AngularJS)

Basically I just want to keep the WebSocket connection alive once the app was started by the user until it is killed manually via a task manager or similar.

I've thoroughly searched every related question on here but they didn't fit my case. I really need this thing to work and would appreciate any help.

Comment: I am not a Cordova expert, but if you were developing this in native ADK, I would have said you have to change your design not to need an open socket in your app. Android can and will exit any background app when needs the resources and apps developed in JS frameworks are not an exception.

Comment: If you can't use things like GCM, normally this should be a background service. https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html not sure if that is possible to develop in cordova

Comment: @farshad90 My app does not close connection immediately, instead, server closes the connection after a while when app does not respond. how can I close the connection as soon as the app goes in the background or exits?

Answer (score 1):

Once Websocket is closed, it will be destroyed. So that you can't make call back function to inform the websocket close event or can't connect from anywhere.

So that, I wrote ***reconnectSocket*** and call from another service.

call this ***reconnectSocket*** in a frequency from another class. (I'm calling for every **5 seconds** interval). If the connection is closed, this will try to connect.

```
private subject: WebSocket;

 reconnectSocket() {
    console.log('reconnecting socket call');

    if (this.subject.readyState == 3) {// If webs-socket closed
      this.subject.close();

      let ws = new WebSocket(CHAT_URL);
      let self = this;
      ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        self.listener(event.data);
      };
      ws.onerror = this.onError;
      ws.onclose = this.onClose;
      ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
      this.subject = ws;
      console.log("websocket reconnected");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use signalr instead of websocket and disable the hardware back button using JavaScript in your app.  Then, the connection should be able to keep alive in your case 1 & 2.

Signalr can use Websocket as well, but actually you don't need to choose it since signalr will choose the best available protocol for you.